# **strong burnt rubber odor** coming from the passenger side REAR tire area

Tags: brakes, smell, lincoln, towncar

I can smell a **strong burnt rubber odour** coming from the passenger side **REAR tire area.**  I sprayed that tire and that area with some water and a lot of steam/smoke arose.  I then sprayed the other three tires and there was no steam/smoke. Any ideas on what this could be?

It's a 2006 Lincoln Town Car.  I just had rear breaks put on about three weeks ago, but this is the first time I noticed this smell.

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: Have the brakes checked by a different shop.

Comment: agree with this, not all shops are created the same ...

Comment: You both made good observations. Listen to them, Joan, and head over to a reputable shop or a dealership.

Comment: Did they also replace the parking brake shoes? Which go inside the rotor. I've seen some of these parking brake shoes actually break apart. Or could just be adjusted too tight

Comment: @cano The 2006 Lincoln Town Car has read disc brakes. There are no parking brake shoes. It uses the caliper to hold the disc.

Comment: Do some detective work. Pull the wheel and look. Maybe mechanics.se is just a diagnosis site after all, but if you can't pull a wheel then maybe just go to a repair shop straight away for every problem and not bother posting a question? Not trying to be rude but trying to understand what answer might work for you that isn't "go find a mechanic."

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like the shoe is not adjusted properly, or is sticking, causing a lot of heat and burnt brakes. Take it back to the shop.

Comment: Yeah and/or the handbrake cable is broken or needs adjusting

Answer (score 0):

Most likely it's a brake fluid leak or the brake is locking on that wheel. It could be something as trivial as a fully grazed out of threads tire.

1. Share a snapshot of this and any other tire.
2. Start the car, pump the brakes a bit and Check for fluid leakage at and around that wheel.
3. Share pictures of the brake rotor and pad from an angle we can judge something like clearance.